# JSON Oracle SQL parsing / unnest embedded JSON data in escaped form

Tags: json, serialization, plsql, gson, deserialization

Here is my JSON stored in a CLOB column:

```
select upJSON from myLocations;

{"values":[
{"nameValuePairs":{"upJSON":"{\"mResults\":[0.0,0.0],\"mProvider\":\"fused\",\"mDistance\":0.0,\"mAltitude\":0.0}","id":"1","updated":"2015-03-30 20:28:51"}},
{"nameValuePairs":{"upJSON":"{\"mResults\":[0.0,0.0],\"mProvider\":\"FINDME\",\"mDistance\":0.0,\"mAltitude\":22.2}","id":"2","updated":"2015-03-30 20:28:53"}},
{"nameValuePairs":{"upJSON":"{\"mResults\":[0.0,0.0],\"mProvider\":\"fused\",\"mDistance\":0.0,\"mAltitude\":0.0}","id":"3","updated":"2015-03-30 20:28:55"}},
{"nameValuePairs":{"upJSON":"{\"mResults\":[0.0,0.0],\"mProvider\":\"fused\",\"mDistance\":0.0,\"mAltitude\":0.0}","id":"4","updated":"2015-03-30 20:28:57"}}
]}
```

(I have inserted newlines for clarity)

Please: What is the SQL (or PL/SQL) needed to select just the value of mProvider, mAltitude, and the id from the 2nd "nameValuePairs" 
(= "FINDME"  and 22.2 and "2") in the example above)
??

Comment: Maybe this can help - http://sourceforge.net/p/pljson/wiki/Home/

Comment: What's your database version? https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADXDB/json.htm

Comment: ('Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production',0);
'PL/SQL Release 12.1.0.2.0 - Production',0);
'CORE 12.1.0.2.0 Production',0);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://odieweblog.wordpress.com/2015/04/12/json_table-chaining/#comment-1025

```
with tmp as (
    SELECT /*+ no_merge */ d.*
    FROM ulocations ul,
         json_table(ul.upjson, '$'
         columns(
         NESTED PATH '$.values[*].nameValuePairs'
               COLUMNS (
                   updated VARCHAR2(19 CHAR)  PATH '$.updated'
                 , id varchar2(9 char)        path '$._id'
                 , upJSON VARCHAR2(2000 CHAR) PATH '$.upJSON'
                )) ) d
    --where d.id = '0'
    )
    select t.updated
        , t.id
        , jt2.*
    from tmp t
       , json_table(t.upJSON, '$'
          columns mProvider varchar2(5) path '$.mProvider'
                , mLongitude  number    path '$.mLongitude'
        ) jt2
    ;
```

Comment: The no_merge hint is perhaps the most elusive aspect of this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using 12c you have access to the native JSON parsing (as long as your CLOB column has an `is json` check constraint).

Some good background is available at:

https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADXDB/json.htm#ADXDB6371

If you're JSON looks something like this:

```
{
    "values": [
        {
            "nameValuePairs": {
                "upJSON": {
                    "mResults": [
                        "0.0",
                        "0.0"
                    ],
                    "mProvider": "fused",
                    "mDistance": "0.0",
                    "mAltitude": "22.2"
                },
                "id": "1",
                "updated": "2015-03-30 20:28:51"
            }
        },
        ...
        ...
```

Although, when I put your snippet from the question into JSONLint it returns:

```
{
    "values": [
        {
            "nameValuePairs": {
                "upJSON": "{\"mResults\":[0.0,0.0],\"mProvider\":\"fused\",\"mDistance\":0.0,\"mAltitude\":0.0}",
                "id": "1",
                "updated": "2015-03-30 20:28:51"
            }
        },
        {
            "nameValuePairs": {
                "upJSON": "{\"mResults\":[0.0,0.0],\"mProvider\":\"FINDME\",\"mDistance\":0.0,\"mAltitude\":22.2}",
                "id": "2",
                "updated": "2015-03-30 20:28:53"
            }
        },
```

Something like the following might get you started:

```
select
    upJSON.values
from
    myLocations
where
    json_value(upJSON, '$nameValuePairs.id' returning varchar2 error on error) = '2';
```

If you want to limit the query to a single ID, you'll need to add a full-text or function-based index to the JSON column.

Comment: what about the \"
which comes over from the gson serialization?

Comment: and what is the SQL (or PL/SQL) needed to select just the value of mProvider, mAltitude, and the id from the 2nd "nameValuePairs" (= "FINDME" and 22.2 and "2") in the example above) ?

Comment: when I type:
select
    upJSON.values
from
    myLocations

I get:
SQL Error: ORA-01747: invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification

Comment: when I type:
select
    *
from
    uLocations
where
    json_value(upJSON, '$nameValuePairs._id' returning varchar2 error on error) = '2'
    
SQL Error: ORA-40462: JSON_VALUE evaluated to no value

Comment: Is there a `check (upJSON is json)` constraint on the table? Can you provide the table DDL? The `...{\"mResults\":[0.0,0....` in the formatted JSON makes me wonder if the JSON is correctly formed.

Comment: CREATE TABLE "GAELUP"."ULOCATIONS" 
   ( "LOGWHEN" TIMESTAMP (6) DEFAULT systimestamp, 
 "IP_ADDRESS" VARCHAR2(256 BYTE), 
 "UPJSON" CLOB
   ) ;
  ALTER TABLE "GAELUP"."ULOCATIONS" ADD CONSTRAINT "UPJSON" CHECK (upJSON IS JSON) ENABLE;

Comment: The JSON is correctly formed. It's the programmatic output from a GSON DOUBLE SERIALIZATION.
Meaning: I gson serialize it in order to store it into SQLlite. Then my Syncadapter gson serializes it again. Perhaps I need to change that. 
I'm guessing there's some gson I can use like ".add" instead of re-serializing.

Comment: However, I would prefer to know how to Oracle double DE-serialize. THAT would be most helpful.

Comment: Once you've got your `upJSON` field returned I suppose you could parse it yourself (manually) to extract the data you require. Or transfer as a JSON record in a separate transfer table to allow parsing. First issue is finding a `json_value` selector that matches your data - maybe you have to go down the array - something like `$values[*].nameValuePairs.id`. I'm afraid I don't have a copy of 12c to hand to test on. Lots of good query examples in the link I've included in my answer. Hope I've been of some help pointing you in the right direction.

Comment: SELECT d.*
    FROM mylocations ul,
         json_table(ul.upjson, '$'
         columns(
         NESTED PATH '$.values[*].nameValuePairs'
               COLUMNS (
                  
                  updated VARCHAR2(19 CHAR)         PATH '$.updated'
                 , id varchar2(9 char) path '$._id'
                 , upJSON VARCHAR2(2000 CHAR)         PATH '$.upJSON'
                )) ) d

             ;

Comment: The ugly above works to deserialize the first stage.
Next I have to deserialize the 2nd stage.